# What is the difference between attribute adjective of Partizip I and Partizip II?

Tags: past-participle, participle

I am studying the participles of the German language. It is mentioned that we can use both of them as attribute adjectives, but what makes them different as an adjective. Is it related to the meaning of the verb or sentence construction?

This [website](https://deutsch.lingolia.com/en/grammar/verbs/participles) is the source of my knowledge. The following examples are mentioned as attribute adjectives of present participle and past participle.

### Partizip 1:

> In einem neben der Kommode **stehenden** Schirmständer steht ein Schirm = In an umbrella stand standing near the bureau, there’s an umbrella

*I am also a little bit confused by the translation of the example. It is difficult for me to find the adjective here.*

### Partizip 2:

> Deshalb lässt sie den **zusammengeklappten** Schirm dort stehen = That’s why she leaves the **folded-up** umbrella there.

Thank you so much for reading my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Partizip 1" and "Partizip 2" are relatively new names for what i learned in school as "Partizip Präsens" and "Partizip Perfekt". These names explain a lot more, i think.

The *Partizip Präsens* describes an action currently taking place and acts quite similar to the english present progressive form:

> der laufende Bub *the running boy*

Or, in your first example:

> In einem [...] stehendem Schirmständer [...]. *In a [...] standing umbrella stand* [...].

This example is not well suited to explain the concept because the wordly translation to english makes it sound weird. German (unlike English) uses "stehend" (*standing*) to describe being located somewhere whereas in proper English does not. One would use "an umbrella stand located at [...]" or maybe "an umbrella stand being [...]. Nevertheless the concept - the umbrella stand is *currently* located/*being* at some place - should be clear with this explanation.

The *Partizip Präsens* indeed acts like an adjective in describing some property of the noun:

> der *große* Wagen   -   der *beschleunigende* Wagen
> (the big car - the accelerating car)

---

The *Partizip Perfekt* is used analogous to the past participle: it is used to construct more complex times or modes (Passiv, Perfekt, Plusquamperfekt, Futur Exact, ...) and it can also describe a property of a noun and hence act as an adjective. The difference to the Partizip Präsens is that the action is not currently taking place but static. Consider:

> the unfolded umbrella

> the unfolding umbrella

The "unfolded" describes a state, the "unfolding" describes an action. The same in german:

> die wandernde Person  (the hiking person)

> die gewanderte Strecke  (the hiked distance)

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your answer. I am grateful for giving your time. Your answer and @HenningKockerbeck 's answer complete each other and it is very difficult to choose only one post as the answer. The part you mention for stehend not only fixed my confusion but also reminded me that I should change my perspective in studying a new language. Also, your different explanations helped me to better understand particples.

Comment: Isn't it more about passive vs. active in the examples? _stehen_ is a bad example, as it does not have a meaningful passive. But consider  _der gekaufte Mann_ vs _der kaufende Mann_. I would rather describe the difference in terms of active/passive than in terms of state/action.

Comment: The *Partizip II* is also called "PPP" - Partizip Perfekt Passiv - for a reason. Yes, it is always in passive mood on itself. Still, the fact remains that it describes a *state* whereas the Partizip Präsens describes an *action*. The latter is *happening* whereas the former has *happened*. In German: Partizip Präsens beschreibt das *Vorgehende*, Partizip Perfekt das *Vorgegangene*.

Answer (score 4):

An adjective adds further description to a noun: "A dog" can refer to *any* dog. "A young dog" can not refer to any dog, but only to a specific subgroup of all dogs, only to a dog with a specific attribute.

But you can not only add a description about what the noun *is*, but also about what the noun *does* or *has done*. "A barking dog" further specifies "a dog" by mentioning the action of the dog. You can do this in German with a *Partizip*, a *participle*.

The *present participle* (Partizip I) refers to something the noun does in the present.

> Der bellende Hund rennt den Zaun entlang.
> The barking dog runs along the fence.

The dog is presently barking.

The *past participle* (Partizip II) refers to something the noun has done (or has been done to it) in the past.

> Der frisch gebadete Hund wälzt sich im Matsch.
> The freshly bathed dog wallows in the mud.

Here, the dog has been bathed in the past.

Regarding your example sentences, in

> In einem neben der Kommode stehenden Schirmständer steht ein Schirm.

The umbrella is standing not just in any umbrella stand, but in the umbrella stand that's standing next to the bureau. The umbrella stand is doing the standing right now, in the present, so we need a *present participle*.

On the other hand, in

> Deshalb lässt sie den zusammengeklappten Schirm dort stehen.

the umbrella isn't getting folded up right now, it has been folded up in the past, so we need a *past participle*.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Thank you so much for spending time in order to answer my question. your answer and @bakunin 's answer complete each other, and it is difficult to choose only one post as the answer. The point you mentioned that the present participle describes present and the other one reflects past cleared the fog in my mind in using participles.