# arbeitende Roboter vs gearbeitete Roboter

Tags: participle

I just learned Partizip 2 and I would like to know the difference between Partizip 1 and 2. What is the difference between ''arbeitende Roboter vs gearbeitete Roboter''? If you give more examples about these topics and difference between them, ı would be thankful.

Comment: gearbeitete Roboter makes no sense. That's the main difference.

Comment: @Eller It could make sense as part of "Aus Metall gearbeitete Roboter".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between attribute adjective of Partizip I and Partizip II?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/69264/what-is-the-difference-between-attribute-adjective-of-partizip-i-and-partizip-ii)

Answer (score 1):

Partizip 1 (often written with roman numerals as Partizip I) implies concurrency. For example, in

> Er schaut den spielenden Kindern zu.
> He watches the playing kids.

the watching and the playing happen concurrently, at the same time.

Partizip 2 (or Partizip II) implies that one action follows another in time. For example, in

> Er fährt das gewaschene Auto in die Garage.
> He drives the washed car into the garage.

the washing of the car comes first, then it is driven back into the garage.

Partizip I is often used to replace a subclause by something akin to an adjective:

> Er schaut den Kindern, die spielen, zu.
> Er schaut den spielenden Kindern zu.

Partizip II can also be used similar to an adjective:

> Er fährt das Auto, das gewaschen worden war, in die Garage.
> Er fährt das gewaschene Auto in die Garage.

It's also used to build the tenses Perfekt, Plusquamperfekt and Futur II:

> Er hat das Auto gewaschen. (Perfekt)
> Er hatte das Auto gewaschen. (Plusquamperfekt)
> Bis zum Wochenende wird er das Auto gewaschen haben. (Futur II)

Additionally, Partizip II is used in passive constructions, like

> Das Auto wird gewaschen.
> Das Auto wurde gewaschen.
> Das Auto wird gewaschen werden.

> Das Auto ist gewaschen.
> Das Auto war gewaschen.
> Das Auto wird gewaschen sein.

In your example,

> arbeitende Roboter

means that the robots are working, and that they are doing it at the same time as the time we're looking at.

> Die arbeitenden Roboter machen eine Menge Lärm.
> The working robots produce a lot of noise.

> gearbeitete Roboter

means that the robots have been worked on in some fashion, and that this happened previously to the time we're looking at.

> Die gearbeiteten Roboter funktionieren jetzt wieder problemlos.
> The worked-on robots are now functioning without problems again.

But "gearbeitete Roboter" feels quite off, because it's hard to tell what it's supposed to mean. If you want to express that the robots have been worked on, something like "bearbeitete Roboter", "überarbeitete Roboter", "gewartete Roboter" would be better.

Comment: Die bearbeiteten/überarbeiteten Roboter, would be the fitting translation for your English translation.

Comment: It would make sense to mention that Partizip I is always active, while Partizip II is (when not used to build a composite tense, and with a few exceptions) always passive in German.